# Can we directly measure vectors' quantities?

Tags: measurements, vectors

Can we perform some kind of experiment that will give us, for example, the $p_x$, $p_y$ and $p_z$ of a particle in a single measurement?

I'm aware that they commute so one measurement will not disturb the others, but I want to know if it is possible to obtain all three components with one single measurement.

The real question I'm trying to get my head around is:
Can we directly measure anything that is NOT a scalar after all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible depending on your definition of a single measurement. I have a contrived example to illustrate.

An object is initially in the center of a spherical shell that has multiple sensors on its inner surface. The object then moves in an unknown direction $\hat n$ with uniform motion. From the single measurement of the single sensor that the object hit, we can deduce $\hat n$.

I suppose there are a few subtleties here. The thing here actually being measured is the electrical signal from the sensor, which you could model as a scalar. But the information one can deduce from that measurement is a vector. Furthermore, it's really the single signal from the hit detector combined with all of the other non-signals that helps us deduce the information. So one could argue this isn't really a *single* measurement.